# On Android, the variable is not being passed from one class to another class via Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, bundle

In this simple code that you can copy and paste into Android Studio to test, there are two classes. In the first class, which is called MainActivity, there is a field for a user to type the name.
In the second class called MainActivity2, there is another field to show what the user typed in the first class called MainActivity1.
However, this code is showing error that it does not recognize the variable "name" in the MainActivity2, in this code snippet: `String receivedName = receiverBundle.getString("name");`

Please can anyone find out how to resolve this little error?

Please, you can copy and paste these simples codes and test in your Android Studio:

````
/*This code is the first Java class that there is a field where the user can write own name:*/
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

MainActivity1:

``` public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText name;
    Button button;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

      name  = findViewById(R.id.name);
      button = findViewById(R.id.button);

        String nameInString = name.getText().toString();

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent senderIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity2.class);
                Bundle senderBundle = new Bundle();
                senderBundle .putString("name", nameInString);
                startActivity(senderIntent);
            }
        });

    }
} 
/* This class there is the field that must appear the name that the user wrote on the first class */
```
MainActivity2:
``` 
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView resultName;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        resultName = findViewById(R.id.nameReceived);

        Intent receiverIntent = getIntent();
        Bundle receiverBundle = receiverIntent.getExtras();
        String receivedName = receiverBundle.getString
                ("name");

        resultName.setText(receivedName);

    }
}
/* Front-end code of MainActivity1*/
``` 
activity_main.xml
``` 
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Send"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.645" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Complete Name:"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.372"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.169" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Type your name"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.501" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
````

/* Front-end code of MainActivity2*/
 `Activity_main2.xml`

````
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nameReceived"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Received name:"
        android:textSize="25dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.476"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.307" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>```
````

[image]

Comment: Can you post the error being thrown?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The init of nameInString should be happen in button.setOnClickListener!

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String nameInString = name.getText().toString();
            Intent senderIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity2.class);
            Bundle senderBundle = new Bundle();
            senderIntent.putExtra("name",nameInString);
            startActivity(senderIntent);
        }
    });
```

**MainActivity2.class**

```
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String username= intent.getStringExtra("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the bundle, and just have something like this:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String username= intent.getStringExtra("name");
```

Comment: For both classes? Or just for the MainActivity2.class?

Comment: in main activity 2

Comment: No more error occurred, but the name written in MainActivity 1 did not appear in MainActivity2
Please can you test?
It is just copy and paste these codes on your Android Studio, test to write a simple name, to pass the written name to other class, and to appear the written name on the MainActivity2.class

Answer (score 0):

Use this to put the name into the intent:

```
senderIntent.putExtra("name",nameInString);
```

Comment: On MainActivity.class, even trying:

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent senderIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity2.class);
                senderIntent.putExtra("name", nameInString);
                startActivity(senderIntent);
            }

It does not work.

Answer (score 0):

for get current text of EditText in Activity1 , get text of editText in setOnClickListener scope and set it for nameInString :

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String nameInString = name.getText().toString();
            Intent senderIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity2.class);
            Bundle senderBundle = new Bundle();
            senderIntent.putExtra("name",nameInString);
            startActivity(senderIntent);
        }
    });
```

in Activity2 :

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String username= intent.getStringExtra("name");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you face two issues:

1. App will crash
2. The value of `resultName` is empty

Regards 1) and 2), the root reason is that you want to use a `bundle` to carry the data, but you didn't put the `bundle` into the `Intent`. And in `MainActivity2` you want to use the `bundle` to get the data directly.
http://prntscr.com/1sdwb9a

Moreover, as other guys said, `intent` can carry many types of values(also contains `bundle`), so no need to use `bundle` in your case.

http://prntscr.com/1sdxv30

Comment: Don't post images of code,  just copy and paste it on your answer.